# Slick Carousel Not Working On Foundation for Apps Dynamic Routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, zurb-foundation

I am using Chrome to run the apps on `localhost:8080`. The slick carousel picks up the JQuery and slick.js just fine when it is in the main `root/client/index.html`, but fails when being called into the view with **dynamic routing** from another template file `root/client/templates/home.html`.

The code below works:

```
<!-- root/client/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="application">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link href="/assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-frame vertical">
      <!--Title bar-->
      <div class="grid-content shrink" style="padding: 0;">
        <div class="primary title-bar">
          <span class="title left">
            <a ur-sref="home">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25">
            </a>
          </span>
          <span class="title right">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-bars"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- The problematic Slick carousel which works fine here, but not when called into the view using ui-router below -->
      <div class="img-slider grid-block shrink">
        <div class="grid-block">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x250">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-block">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x250">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-block">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x250">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Uncomment this part to call the above carousel from another template
      <div ng-class="['ui-animation']" ui-view class="hole grid-block wrap"></div>
      -->

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>     
    <!-- Looks like the template file cannot read slick.js here -->   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('.img-slider').slick({
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 4000,
          arrows: true,
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 500,
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code below is the template to be called into the `ui-view` portion above:

```
<!-- root/client/templates/home.html -->
---
name: home
url: /
animationIn: fadeIn
---

<div class="img-slider grid-block shrink">
  <div class="grid-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x250">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x250">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

I suspect it's the [JQuery vs Angular issue](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/21714-how-do-i-use-jquery-with-foundation-for-apps) or the serving from `file://` instead of `http://`, but I've tried both and the carousel is still not working, and appears like normal divs stacked next to one another.

Comment: I know it's not an answer to this specific slick question, but I was using slick carousel for a while with angularjs and having a lot of issues. One solution is to use angular-slick, found at http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/ , but I eventually switched to simply using the angularjs carousel. Fixed 99% of my carousel problems instantly and it's super easy to implement!

Comment: Can you point me to some docs for angularjs carousel?

Comment: Sure, let me Google that for you. http://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk . As you can see, it's as easy as using the built-in `<carousel>` and `<slide>` tags from AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a linking issue. You are using an absolute path here for example:

```
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
```

Try to load the file using a relative path.

Comment: Thank @Jackson but it didn't work. The script imports were pre-configured by the framework. The problem seems to come from the external template file `root/client/templates/home.html` not reading `slick.min.js` in the main `index.html` file.

Comment: What do you mean it's not reading it? If you open the developer tools do you see 404 (NOT FOUND)?

Comment: Sorry, it actually get `slick.min.js` alright. As mentioned earlier it works when the carousel code exists in the same file, but not when it's called from outside. I think at some point the jQuery code in `$(document).ready()` may have run before the outside template was actually loaded.

Comment: Ah ok so if you are loading the carousel markup dynamically then you would need to initiate the carousel after the markup is loaded. I don't know much about angularjs but i presume there is a callback function that you can use.